# Maven error message Artifact has no file

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm getting tons and tons of these error messages on my build. However it seems to have no effect on passing or failing the build. Does anyone know where this comes from ?

Edit -> it does appear to be related to the reporting plugin. This is all I have for the reporting section

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- use mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
                <check/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

and here are the plugins I have

```
<plugins>
    <!-- fixes bug running coverage for jdk 1.7 -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <check>
                <branchRate>100</branchRate>
                <lineRate>100</lineRate>
                <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                <totalBranchRate>100</totalBranchRate>
                <totalLineRate>100</totalLineRate>
                <packageLineRate>100</packageLineRate>
                <packageBranchRate>100</packageBranchRate>
                <!--<regexes>-->
                <!--<regex>-->
                <!--<pattern>com.example.reallyimportant.*</pattern>-->
                <!--<branchRate>90</branchRate>-->
                <!--<lineRate>80</lineRate>-->
                <!--</regex>-->
                <!--<regex>-->
                <!--<pattern>com.example.boringcode.*</pattern>-->
                <!--<branchRate>40</branchRate>-->
                <!--<lineRate>30</lineRate>-->
                <!--</regex>-->
                <!--</regexes>-->
            </check>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>clean</id>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>package</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>enforce-maven-3</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireMavenVersion>
                            <version>3.0.4</version>
                        </requireMavenVersion>
                    </rules>
                    <fail>true</fail>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>enforce-logging-deps</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <bannedDependencies>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </bannedDependencies>
                    </rules>
                    <fail>true</fail>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>PhantomJS Unit Testing</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/phantomjs/1.7.0/phantomjs</executable>
            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/js</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>
                <argument>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/phantomjs/runner.js</argument>
                <argument>qunit-require-tests.html</argument>
                <!-- surefire report output -->
                <argument>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/qunit</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.timurstrekalov</groupId>
        <artifactId>saga-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>coverage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <baseDir>${project.basedir}</baseDir>
            <includes>src/test/js/qunit-require-tests.html</includes>
            <noInstrumentPatterns>
                <pattern>.+\/libs\/.+js</pattern>
                <pattern>.+\/test\/.+js</pattern>
            </noInstrumentPatterns>
            <sourcesToPreload>
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/c*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/f*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/m*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/r*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/t*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/u*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/v*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/w*/**/*.js,
                src/main/webapp/resources/js/*.js
            </sourcesToPreload>
            <outputStrategy>BOTH</outputStrategy>
            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/saga</outputDir>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

and then the output

```
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] Artifact: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: junit:junit-dep:jar:4.10 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.apache.commons:commons-proxy:jar:1.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.2 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3.RC2 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.4.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.4.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.0.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.8 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.1 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: wlec:wlec-client-web-conf:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: wlec:wlec-client-webservice:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: wlec:wlec-data:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: wlec:wlec-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2 has no file.
```

Comment: I've been using maven 3 for a while and I've never seen this error. It could either a plugin or the configuration of one of the plugins in your pom (maybe you have some extra configuration in your dependency plugin?). Try running maven with the `-X` flag to get more information, another option is to generate the effective pom and check if there's something odd there, you can do that by running `mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effpom.xml`

Comment: can u show us the pom.xml, if you could? and also img of your navigator probably

Comment: is there a connection problem with the remote repositories or the proxy? if you rename the local repo are the artifacts re-downloaded?

Comment: These errors come up while generating reports within Maven. We will need to see pom in order to tell you exactly which plugin they are coming from. I have seen instances where people experience this with the project-info plugins.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: Take a look inside your .m2 folder and look for org.apache.commons:commons-proxy:jar, for example. Is it there?  If not, try to rename your "repository" folder, inside .m2, and run __mvn install__ outside your IDE, directly in shell/prompt.  
The dependencies will be downloaded again. Take a look if the JAR files are there.  If the problem are still happening, check if you aren't have connections problems with the repositories.  Are you behind a firewall or proxy? Are you using Artifactory or something like this?

Answer (score 7):

maybe because the plugin 'Maven Project Info Reports Plugin' problem, I found the issue on jira: [enter link description here](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPIR-251)

as advised, try

```
<reporting>
    <plugins> ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
                    ...
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

This plugin is not in your config, maybe it is referenced by other.